# Is there a command line tool that can modify the Podfile?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, podfile

I want to add a framework to my project using Cocoapods. But I don't want to change Podfile manually. I want to use a command line to edit the Podfile like this:

```sh
some_command ./Podfile --add AFNetworking --target MyTarget
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't such command.

The closer you can do is creating a `.sh` file that opens the `Podfile` and writes on it. Example:

podwrite.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

FILE="Path/To/Podfile"

/bin/cat <<EOM >$FILE
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

target 'MyTarget' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'AFNetworking'
end

EOM
```

Call via terminal:

```
sh podwrite.sh
```

Output on the podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

target 'MyTarget' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'AFNetworking'
end
```

Comment: won't that overwrite the existing Podfile?